# Rsyslog Remote Logging: Garbled Text when using TLS

Tags: linux, logging, rsyslog

I've set up Rsyslog with TLS on two Debian machines and configured remote logging (`log-server`, `log-shipper`). However, I am getting "garbled" Text in the logs on the server:

```
Oct 22 07:58:45 log-shipper.example.org #000��}̪��#0009#000k#000�#000�#000��|��#0003#000g#000E#000�#000#026#001#000#000J#000#027#000#000#000#026#000#000#000#005#000#005#001#000#000#000#000�#001#000#001#000#000##000#000
Oct 22 07:58:45 log-shipper.example.org #000#014
Oct 22 07:58:46 log-shipper.example.org #026#003#001#000�#001#000#000�#003#003[̓#006�: �Q#035�'Q#035�o#014�#001V<��[��|ng�[ܴ#000#000r�,��̩���
```

Basically I followed the Rsyslog docs [here](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/tutorials/tls_cert_summary.html), and also followed other tutorials on the Internet, but the result is always the same.

After having spent 2 days on this, I'm out of ideas. Anyone has a hint, or experienced it too?

Server config:

```
$ModLoad imtcp # TCP listener

# make gtls driver the default
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls

# certificate files
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /etc/ssl/certs/server-cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/server-key.pem

$InputTCPServerStreamDriverMode 1 # run driver in TLS-only mode
$InputTCPServerStreamDriverAuthMode anon
$InputTCPServerRun 5822 # start up listener at port 5822
```

Client config:

```
# make gtls driver the default
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls

# certificate files
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /var/tmp/ca.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /var/tmp/storage1-cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /var/tmp/storage1-key.pem

$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode anon
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1 # run driver in TLS-only mode
*.* @@(o)log-server.example.org:5822 # forward everything to remote server
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually means there's something wrong with encryption, check what `syslog` says when `rsyslog` service is starting, if it's complaining about anything. Other than that, how did you setup Certificate Authority, as that's the trickiest part of whole setup?
Also, is your `$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile` same on both server?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I would comment but not enough rep in this community. I have seen garbled text like that before when I was doing an NMAP scan of a server and watching the results in Syslog. Someone has posted a longer snippet of the attack:

https://superuser.com/questions/1091351/rsyslogd-log-entry-about-attack-created-by-unknown-application

Please take a look and see if the logs reflect that attack.

I have also noticed while setting up logging to an Rsyslog server the inclusion of the `#014` character (ie when I set up conversion from Windows EventLog events to Rsyslog server) but without the garbled text. When I switched to another Syslog format (ie getting logs in BSD Syslog format) I was no longer getting the `#014` character. You may want to consider looking into another log collection software like NXLog for this to collect and centralize log collection.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 18.04 I used the following syntax:

```
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-cert.pem 
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /etc/ssl/certs/server-cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/server-key.pem

# provides TCP syslog reception with encryption (TLS)
module(load="imtcp" StreamDriver.Name="gtls" StreamDriver.Mode="1" StreamDriver.AuthMode="anon")
input(type="imtcp" port="6514" )
```